# Poisson Process Service Queue

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Consider a single-server queue with Poisson rate λ arrivals and Exponential rate μ>λ service times, but make the following modification: Fix some α∈(λ/μ,1).When a service time is complete, with probability 1−α the customer rejoins the end of the queue instead of leaving the system as usual

1. By relating the modified queue to a certain M/M/1 queue, find the stationary distribution for the number of customers in the system
2. Using Little’s formula, L=λW, find the long run average time spent in the queue until being served for the first time.

Comment: This is the simplest example of an open Jackson network. It is equivalent to a M/M/1 queue with arrival rate $(1-\alpha)\lambda$. I trust you can figure out the rest.